# Leaflet pop-up does not work with Geojson data

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

I have a geojson file(Polygons).I want to display it on a leaflet map and when user clicks on a polygon, a popup with an information should be visible. The information is 'type'.  I am able to see the layer but no pop up window  appears when i click on any polygon.  here is the geojson sample:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "osm_id": "32741378",
      "name": "Azam Television",
      "type": "industrial"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [39.2463013, -6.8431187],
          [39.2470392, -6.8427426],
          [39.2471654, -6.8429866],
          [39.2464274, -6.8433627],
          [39.2463013, -6.8431187]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>leaflet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 800px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


    var map = L.map('map').setView([ 13.3844, 52.5177], 12);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);



 $.getJSON("landuse.geojson",function(landuse){

        L.geoJson(landuse ,{
                    style:  function (feature)
                        {
                            return {"color": "#78c679","weight": 5,"opacity": 0.9}
                        }
                },
                {
                    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
                             layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
                        }
                }
        ).addTo(map);

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: i am viewing in FireFox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simply because your `onEachFeature` option should be a member of the 2nd argument (options) of `L.geoJSon` factory, alongside `style` option, rather than a 3rd argument:

```js
L.geoJson(landuse, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      "color": "#78c679",
      "weight": 5,
      "opacity": 0.9
    }
  },
  // Put onEachFeature within the options object, not as 3rd argument.
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
  }
}/*, { // Original position (as 3rd argument) of onEachFeature.
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
  }
}*/).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/J1VqeTQuA4m5y7J8m88d?p=preview